# Hibernate filter not working with parent domain

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class, hibernate-filters

I have two domain in parent child structure.

First one is :-

```
class Client {

    String xyz
    static belongsTo = [site: Site]

 static hibernateFilters = {
        siteFilter(condition: ':siteId = site_id', types: 'long')
    }
}
```

And second one is.

```
class TicketDetail {

    Date date
    Client client
}
```

If I am directly accessing to Client domain like.

Client.searchByAlphabet(params).list(params)

Hibernate filter working fine.But when I am using criteria on TicketDetail like .

```
 client {
         site {
               eq('id', currentSiteId)
              }
        }
projections {
                distinct 'client'
            }
```

Then Hibernate filter on Client domain not working.How can i active hibernate filter when accessing child domain from parent domain.

Answer (score 0):

Use createAlias... E.G.

```
class Customer {
   String name
   Account account
   BigDecimal minAccountBalance
   ...
}

class Account {
   BigDecimal currentBalance
   ...
}

Customer.createCriteria().list(){
      createAlias('account', 'acc')
      gtProperty('acc.currentBalance', 'minAccountBalance')
    }
```

Comment: I am not getting any error but my hibernateFilters not working. I am getting all record. But according to filter it should return record only for selected site Id.